# access BackgroundService from controller in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, background-service

I just need to access my **BackgroundService** from a controller.
Since BackgroundServices are injected with

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyBackgroundService>()
```

How can I use it from a Controller class?

Comment: add constructor to controller `public ControllerName(IHostedService service){ .. }` Did you try to read documentation before asking here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: Yes, I did. 
I need BackgroundService injected in my controller, not IHostedService interface. I can have more than one BackgroundService, and all are injected as services.AddSingleton<IHostedService,...>()

Comment: Something to be very careful about is aspnet registers HostedServices as **transient** instances. So any time you receive an instance, it is **not** the instance that had `Start()` invoked on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
public interface IHostedServiceAccessor<T> where T : IHostedService
{
  T Service { get; }
}

public class HostedServiceAccessor<T> : IHostedServiceAccessor<T>
  where T : IHostedService
{
  public HostedServiceAccessor(IEnumerable<IHostedService> hostedServices)
  {
    foreach (var service in hostedServices) {
      if (service is T match) {
        Service = match;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  public T Service { get; }
}
```

Then in `Startup`:

```
services.AddTransient<IHostedServiceAccessor<MyBackgroundService>, HostedServiceAccessor<MyBackgroundService>>();
```

And in my class that needs access to the background service...

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly MyBackgroundService _service;

  public MyClass(IHostedServiceAccessor<MyBackgroundService> accessor)
  {
    _service = accessor.Service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessor));
  }
}
```

Comment: A word of warning--after encountering some unusual behavior, note that while the IHostedService implementation acts like a singleton, its state will be inaccessible. For example, if you add `private readonly Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();` to the service class and observe it when the service starts vs when obtained via IHostedServiceAccessor, you'll notice it's two different values.

Comment: @UtopiaLtd Don't add the background service as `Transient` but as a `Singleton`. The microsoft documentation states that the hosted service must create the scopes by itself, as if you add it as `Scoped`, you'll probably use disposed objects.

Comment: As of .NET 5.0 an API derives from ControllerBase. It would be better if this answer addressed how a "MyController" deriving from ControllerBase is to invoke BackgroundService.

Answer (score 10):

In the end I've injected `IEnumerable<IHostedService>` in the controller and filtered by Type:`background.FirstOrDefault(w => w.GetType() == typeof(MyBackgroundService)`

Answer (score 0):

Add BackgroundService in ConfigureServices function:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ListenerService>();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Inject in the Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostedService listenerService;

    public ValuesController(IHostedService listenerService)
    {
        this.listenerService = listenerService;
    }
}
```

I used BackgroundService to spin up multiple listeners for AWSSQS Listeners. If consumer wants to spin new listener then it could be done by POSTing to a Controller method (end point).